# Continuity of Volterra operator in $L^p[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The Volterra operator is defined as
$$
V f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(y) d y, \quad \text { for } x \in[0,1]
$$
I want to show that $
V$ maps $L^{p}[0,1]$ continuously into itself for each $1 \leq p \leq \infty
$. And likewise $
V: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ is continuous

My attempt is to show in $L^p[0,1]$, $V$ is bounded and since $V$ is linear, it is continuous. So far I have $\|Vf(x)-Vg(x)\|_p=\|\int_{0}^{x}(f(x)-g(x))\|_p \leq \int_{0}^{x}\|f(x)-g(x)\|_p$. 
Next I'm trying to use Holder's inequality and show this is bounded, is my thought correct? Also how to show that it maps to itself part? Should I prove $Vf(x)\in L^p[0,1]$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want a bound of the form $\|Vf\|_{L^p}\leq C\|f\|_{L^p},$ and similar for the continuous version. Think about how big $x$ can get in the work you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prove that $Vf\in L^p[0,1]$. This is trivial because $Vf$ is continuous, so it's bounded, and all bounded function are in $L^p[0,1]$ given that the measure of $[0,1]$ is finite.

As for bounded, 
\begin{align}
\left\|Vf\right\|_p
&=\left(\int_0^1\left|\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\right|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}
\leq\left(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|\,dt\right)^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}\\ \ \\
&\leq\left(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1|f(t)|\,dt\right)^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}
=\int_0^1|f(t)|\,dt\\ \ \\
&\leq\|f\|_p\|1\|_q=\|f\|_p,
\end{align}
so $V$ is bounded and $\|V\|=1$.